# Can the Losanitsch triangle be derived from the Pascal's triangle?

Tags: number-theory

Assuming of course that the Losanich triangle is a real thing. I saw it on Wikipedia and you know how people put fake stuff on their sometimes, so let me know if its fake.

Comment: Definition of rarely used term?  Link to page?  Which of the two spellings is correct?

Comment: Do you mean Lozanić's triangle?

Comment: By German spelling, Losanitsch is correct. By original spelling, Lozanić is correct. As for Losanich, I don't know in what context that would be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lozanić's triangle (or Losanitsch's triangle, to use the Germanized spelling) is a real thing, but you're wise to be wary of Wikipedia.

And in answer to your main question, yes, Lozanić's triangle can be derived from Pascal's triangle. Write Pascal's triangle as usual. Then write a more "spacious" copy of Pascal's triangle, in which each cell is separated in the surrounding rows and columns by 0s, like so:

0

0 0

0 1 0

0 0 0 0

0 1 0 1 0

0 0 0 0 0 0

0 1 0 2 0 1 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 1 0 3 0 3 0 1 0

Overlay the padded Pascal's triangle over the original triangle and subtract the padded triangle from the original triangle, starting at the top and propagating the changes to the rows below (by which I mean changing the rows below so that each number is still the sum of the two numbers above; technically you only need to do this propagation for the two rows below at a time because you'll have actual subtractions again two rows down).

After propagating the first set of changes, you'll have:

1

1 1

1 1 1

1 2 2 1

1 3 4 3 1

1 4 7 7 4 1

1 5111411 5 1

After the second set of changes:

1

1 1

1 1 1

1 2 2 1

1 2 4 2 1

1 3 6 6 3 1

1 4 912 9 4 1

And so on and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but the answer is a tad messy.  Write, as usual, the $k$-th number in the $n$-th row of Pascal's triangle as the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}$.  And call the $k$-th number in the $n$-th row of the Losanitsch triangle (that is the spelling I learned) as
$L(n,k)$. And let the expression $[n \mbox{ odd or } k \mbox{ even}]$ stand for 1 if $n$ is odd or $k$ is even and for zero otherwise.

Then
$$
L(n,k) = \frac{1}{2}  \binom{n}{k} +
\frac{1}{2} [n \mbox{ odd or } k \mbox{ even}] \binom{\lfloor \frac{1}{2}n\rfloor}{\lfloor\frac{1}{2}k\rfloor}
$$
where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ means the largest integer not exceeding $x$.

So for large $n$, row $n$ of the Losanitsch triangle is very roughly a bit more than half of row $n$ of the Pascal triangle.

Tryit -- rows $10$ of the two triangles (where the first row is row $0$) are
$$
\begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
1 & 5 & 25 & 60 & 110 & 126 & 110 & 60 & 25 & 5 & 1 \\
1 & 10 & 45 & 120 &  210 & 252 &210 & 120 & 45 & 10 & 1
\end{array}
$$